# WPF/Windows 8 app DataTemplate Databind Event

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a RichTextBox control inside a DataTemplate for a ListView. The idea is that I want to dynamically add Runs/InlineUIElements/images, etc to the rich text boxes in the Listview at Bind time. The problem is there's no ondatabinding or similar event. I tried the Loaded event of the RichTextBox but it appears that WPF reuses controls so the content was being messed up when I scrolled (putting the wrong content in the wrong order, because the load events were firing during scroll). I should also mention the binding to the ListView is taking place in the codebehind, by manually adding rows to the ListView.Items collection.

Relevant markup

```
 <ListView Background="#F7F7F7" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Foreground="Black" x:Name="chatPane" Grid.Row="1" 
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" SelectionMode="Multiple"
              ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource messageTypeDataTemplateSelector}" SelectionChanged="ChatPane_OnSelectionChanged">
        </ListView>

<common:MessageTypeDataTemplateSelector 
        TextMessageTemplate="{StaticResource TextMessage}" 
        EnterMessageTemplate="{StaticResource EnterMessage}" 
        ExitMessageTemplate="{StaticResource ExitMessage}"
        TimestampMessageTemplate="{StaticResource TimestampMessage}"
        ImageMessageTemplate="{StaticResource ImageMessage}"
        x:Key="messageTypeDataTemplateSelector" />

<DataTemplate x:Key="TextMessage">
        <Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="3" RowSpan="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition  Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="70*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding UserName}" Visibility="{Binding Source={StaticResource chatSettings}, Path=HideAvatars, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibility}}" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="0" Width="150" />
            <Image VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="{Binding AvatarUrl}" Visibility="{Binding Source={StaticResource chatSettings}, Path=ShowAvatars, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibility}}" Grid.Column="0" Width="60" Margin="0,0,10,0" />
            <TextBlock Text=" : " Visibility="{Binding Source={StaticResource chatSettings}, Path=HideAvatars, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibility}}" Grid.Column="1"  />
            <RichTextBlock Loaded="FrameworkElement_OnLoaded" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="2" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Just so you know, Windows 8 Store apps do not use WPF. They are using Windows Runtime (RT), which is not WPF and not Silverlight, though sharing some similarities between the two. I know this doesn't answer your question, but just sharing since it could come in handy when looking through the MSDN documentation.

Comment: And what does your FrameworkElement_OnLoaded method look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are absolutely correct. There is no OnDataBinding event in WinRT. How about this idea:

Create an AttachedProperty for the RichTextBlock (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011(v=vs.110).aspx) and then Bind your item to that. When you register the Attached Property, in the FrameworkPropertyMetadata, you can specify a PropertyChangedCallback that will fire whenever the Attached Property's value changes. Like this:

For now, to make sure it works, in your current .xaml.cs file do the following:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty RichTextBlockItemProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
  "RichTextBlockItem",
  typeof(object),
  typeof(RichTextBlock),
  new PropertyMetadata(null, RichTextBlockItemChanged)
);

// Don't forget this!
public static object GetRichTextBlockItem(DependencyObject obj)
{
    return (object)obj.GetValue(RichTextBlockItemProperty);
}

// And this!
public static void SetRichTextBlockItem(DependencyObject obj, object value)
{
   obj.SetValue(RichTextBlockItemProperty, value);
}

public void RichTextBlockItemChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Here you can do whatever you wish. This method will fire when the item is bound.
    // d is the RichTextBlock object.
    // e.NewValue is the value that was just bound.
    // So, from here you can dynamically add your Runs/Images/etc
}
```

And then in your .xaml file make sure you add a local namespace so you can do this:

```
<Page .... xmlns:local="using:CurrentXamlPageNamespace".../>

<DataTemplate x:Key="TextMessage">
    <Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="3" RowSpan="1">
        <!-- I got rid of the other xaml just to hightlight my answer. But you still need it. -->
        <RichTextBlock local:RichTextBlock.RichTextBlockItem="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="2" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Hmm. I think I get what you're trying to do here, but could you show me some sample XAML? The problem is that not all the items bound to this ListView are going to have a RichTextBox. That's why I have the custom data template jazz going on. Also, where exactly would that code above live? In the .xaml.cs Page file I'm working in?

Comment: Ok, I'll update my code but if you have other Templates without RichTextBlocks then you may be able to create a more general Dependency Property that you can bind to in all of your Templates.

Comment: Hmm, does Windows Runtime support FrameworkPropertyMetadata? The type or namespace name 'FrameworkPropertyMetadata' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: My mistake, I fixed it. PropertyMetadata.

Comment: Ahh, PropertyMetaData is valid. But RichTextBlockItemProperty, where should that be defined? I have a feeling this needs to be global somehow and not in the .xaml.cs file of the page I'm in, because I'm getting build errors:

The member "RichTextBlockItem" is not recognized or is not accessible

Comment: Oops, sorry. I suspect I know why. Sorry, I was not using Visual Studio when I wrote the answer. I'll try in Visual Studio now. Sorry about that. But make sure you add the GetRichTextBlockItem and SetRichTextBlockItem methods.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43161/discussion-between-chrislava-and-richthofen)